# PHP : tell php if xxx else do nothing

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to use one line and one if statement.

```
(isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) ? delete_cookie($_COOKIE['uid']) : do_nothing;
```

but only one condition, else just do nothing. How can I  achieve this?

Comment: `isset($_COOKIE['uid']) && delete_cookie($_COOKIE['uid']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) delete_cookie($_COOKIE['uid']);
```

If only one statement is executed within an if statement it can be written inline without the need for braces. However I would consider the use of braces for readability

Answer (score 3):

This type of function is probably suited to an `if` condition

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['uid'])){ deleteCookie($_COOKIE['uid']); }
```

But if you wanted to use a ternary operator:

```
$result = isset($_COOKIE['uid']) ? deleteCookie($_COOKIE['uid']) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {
   delete_cookie($_COOKIE['uid']);
}
```

if you want single line statement

```
(isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) ? delete_cookie($_COOKIE['uid']) : '';
```

Comment: I know your method works but the question does state they want to use "one line if statement".

Answer (score 0):

```
(isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) ? delete_cookie($_COOKIE['uid']) : null;
```

Probably it will work, if not try to change `null` to `false`.